# How do I setup the credit card optional data in BTCard to have to Braintree backend deliver a valid token in swift 4?

Tags: swift, sdk, tokenize, braintree, credit-card

The developer documentation as of July 2019 for the Braintree SDK offers the standard :

```
let braintreeClient = BTAPIClient(authorization: "<#CLIENT_AUTHORIZATION#>")!
let cardClient = BTCardClient(apiClient: braintreeClient)
let card = BTCard(number: "4111111111111111", expirationMonth: "12", expirationYear: "2018", cvv: nil)
cardClient.tokenizeCard(card) { (tokenizedCard, error) in
    // Communicate the tokenizedCard.nonce to your server, or handle error
}
```

But when the postal code is needed in the initialization the class accepts a NSDictionary of parameters.  The problem is the key doesn't match the Braintree SDK properties

I have used:

```
let cardParameters: [String: Any] = [number:"4111111111111111",expirationMonth: "12", expirationYear: "2018", cvv: "111", postalCode: "94107"]
let card = BTCard.init(parameters: cardParameters)

The errors say : "Must provide postal code" or "cvv must be provided"
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use the built in properties initializing the BTCard object and match them rather than use a NSDictionary.  So this works:

```
let braintreeClient = BTAPIClient(authorization: "<#CLIENT_AUTHORIZATION#>")!
let cardClient = BTCardClient(apiClient: braintreeClient)
let card = BTCard.init()
card.number = "4111111111111111"
card.expirationMonth = "12"
card.expirationYear = "2018"
card.cvv = "111"
card.postalCode = "94107"

cardClient.tokenizeCard(card) { (tokenizedCard, error) in
    // Communicate the tokenizedCard.nonce to your server, or handle error
}
```

This way the BTCard object returns the acceptable keys...this took me a few hours trying different things to get to this answer.  Braintree and their docs don't offer this as a example yet its was the only way it works for me.

(Each of your backends may curate this data prior to sending it to Braintree but this will help when you integrate)